# Rails+Cucumber+Capybara: Compare expected table with HTML table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara

I have the following step:

```
Then I should see the following games:
    | soccer      | 94040     | "friendly"  |
    | basketball  | 94050     | "competition"|
```

And I have the following step definition:

```
Then /^I should see the following games:$/ do |expected_table|
  table_results = page.find('#games_results_table')
end
```

If I do `puts table_results` I get:

```
#<Capybara::Element tag="table" path="/html/body/div[2]/table">
```

I have tried doing this in order to compare expected_table with the table_results:

```
expected_table.diff!(table_results)
```

But I get this error:

```
undefined method `transpose' for #<Capybara::Element tag="table" path="/html/body/div[2]/table"> (NoMethodError)
```

Notice that the view that is rendering the table is this:

```
<div class="page-header">
  <h1>Games</h1>
  <table id="games_results_table" class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
      <th>Sport Type</th>
      <th>Zip Code</th>
      <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
      <% @games.each do |game| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= game.sport_type %></td>
          <td><%= game.zip_code %></td>
          <td><%= game.description %></td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
  </table>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the Cucumber book](http://pragprog.com/book/hwcuc/the-cucumber-book), on the `table#diff!` method:

> It takes a single argument which it expects to be an Array of Array representing rows and columns. If all the values are equal, the step definition passes. If not, the step definition fails and a diff is printed out.

So you need to map your Capybara table into an array of arrays, something like:

```
table_results = page.find('#games_results_table tr').map do |row|
    row.children.map do |cell|
        cell.text
    end
end
```

You may have to experiment with this - I can't think offhand of the exact Capybara methods to do this.  The aim is to turn the Capybara element into an array of arrays equivalent to:

```
table_result = [
    ['Sport Type', 'Zip Code', 'Description'],
    ['Extreme Ironing', '12345', 'Participants perform ironing tasks in improbably extreme surroundings'],
    # etc - whatever is on the page
]
```

Comment: This [gist](https://gist.github.com/denmarkin/1334262) provides a working example of comparing a table in your feature to a table in your generated HTML.